# After changing gst-lib-version app falls down

Tags: android, gstreamer, native-code

I'm writing an Android App witch recieves udp videostreem and render it on display.

Before changing version of gstreamer from Congo to 1.4.0 the App stops with this:

```
09-03 15:38:20.630: D/GStreamer(12874): Surface destroyed
09-03 15:38:20.640: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12874): 0:04:04.929366696 0x521ecd20 jni/Piovra.c:907:gst_native_surface_finalize Releasing Native Window 0x522de008
09-03 15:38:21.020: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12874): 0:04:05.317334029 0x521ecd20 jni/Piovra.c:823:gst_native_finalize Quitting video main loop...
09-03 15:38:21.020: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12874): 0:04:05.317554696 0x521ecd20 jni/Piovra.c:827:gst_native_finalize Waiting for threads to finish...
09-03 15:38:21.020: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12874): 0:04:05.317907696 0x522ec220 jni/Piovra.c:368:video_app_function Exited main loop
09-03 15:38:21.030: D/dalvikvm(12874): threadid=13: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
09-03 15:38:21.030: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12874): 0:04:05.322372363 0x522ec220 jni/Piovra.c:94:detach_current_thread Detaching thread 0x522ec220
09-03 15:38:21.030: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12874): 0:04:05.323297030 0x521ecd20 jni/Piovra.c:833:gst_native_finalize Deleting GlobalRef for app object at 0x1d200242
09-03 15:38:21.030: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12874): 0:04:05.323552030 0x521ecd20 jni/Piovra.c:835:gst_native_finalize Freeing CustomData at 0x522ec960
09-03 15:38:21.030: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12874): 0:04:05.323775030 0x521ecd20 jni/Piovra.c:838:gst_native_finalize Done finalizing
09-03 15:38:21.280: D/dalvikvm(12874): JIT unchain all for threadid=17
09-03 15:38:21.570: D/dalvikvm(12874): JIT unchain all for threadid=17
```

After changing of version of gstreamer from Congo to 1.4.0:

```
09-03 15:29:40.140: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:52.864815716 0x51e21940 jni/Piovra.c:923:gst_native_pause Setting state to PAUSED
09-03 15:29:40.140: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:52.864933383 0x51e21940 jni/Piovra.c:113:set_ui_message Setting message to: Setting state to PAUSED
09-03 15:29:40.150: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:52.877019716 0x51f7cec0 jni/Piovra.c:113:set_ui_message Setting message to: State changed to PAUSED
09-03 15:29:40.150: E/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:52.877265716 0x51f7cec0 jni/Piovra.c:117:set_ui_message Failed to call Java method
09-03 15:29:40.660: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:53.384060383 0x51e21940 jni/Piovra.c:890:gst_native_finalize Quitting video main loop...
09-03 15:29:40.660: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:53.385065716 0x51e21940 jni/Piovra.c:894:gst_native_finalize Waiting for threads to finish...
09-03 15:29:40.660: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:53.385104050 0x51f7cec0 jni/Piovra.c:435:video_app_function Exited main loop
09-03 15:29:40.660: W/libEGL(12065): eglTerminate() called w/ 2 objects remaining
09-03 15:29:40.660: D/dalvikvm(12065): threadid=13: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
09-03 15:29:40.660: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:53.391390716 0x51f7cec0 jni/Piovra.c:94:detach_current_thread Detaching thread 0x51f7cec0
09-03 15:29:40.660: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:53.392429716 0x51e21940 jni/Piovra.c:900:gst_native_finalize Deleting GlobalRef for app object at 0x1d20023e
09-03 15:29:40.660: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:53.392723383 0x51e21940 jni/Piovra.c:902:gst_native_finalize Freeing CustomData at 0x51fa0ab8
09-03 15:29:40.660: D/GStreamer+Piovra(12065): 0:06:53.393165383 0x51e21940 jni/Piovra.c:905:gst_native_finalize Done finalizing
09-03 15:29:40.680: E/libEGL(12065): validate_display:253 error 3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
09-03 15:29:40.680: E/libEGL(12065): eglMakeCurrent:511 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-03 15:29:40.680: E/libEGL(12065): validate_display:253 error 3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
09-03 15:29:40.680: E/libEGL(12065): eglMakeCurrent:511 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-03 15:30:00.030: E/libEGL(12065): validate_display:253 error 3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
09-03 15:30:00.030: E/libEGL(12065): eglMakeCurrent:511 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-03 15:30:00.030: E/libEGL(12065): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
09-03 15:30:00.030: E/libEGL(12065): validate_display:253 error 3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
09-03 15:30:00.030: E/libEGL(12065): eglMakeCurrent:511 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-03 15:30:00.030: W/ManagedEGLContext(12065): doTerminate failed: EGL count is 0 but managed count is 1
```

Any guesses about?